# Is there anyway to style Messages.app's message view?

Tags: macos, messages

Messages.app is a one of my favorite applications now-a-days because it allows me to reach my friends portable devices and computers with great ease and speed. But it didn't really hit the bar with looking as great as messages did on iOS. Images sent don't have proper padding in the bubbles, the typography is awful, and you know what - the whole bubble thing isn't that great anyways.

I peeked around in the .app to see if there was any immediate way I could amend the ugliness of the app and found nothing Kyle-edible. My question is this - is it possible to get custom message views much like Adium or Skype has in Messages for OSX? If it is, how can it be done?

If it's at all possible by anybody, I'd like to send this challenge off to some talented designers to make Messages the great application it should be.

Comment: Is it really that bad?  I wonder if the size of the window has a lot to do with it.  I generally keep mine very small and narrow, which now that I think about it more closely matches the iOS screen size, so I guess I never noticed any problems.  It feels pretty consistent with the iOS application for me.

Answer (score 1):

The styling is embedded into the app and currently cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Styling cannot be changed, but fonts can be.

[image]

Furthermore, the plist file for iChat, under /Library/Preferences/com.Apple.iChat.plist contains settings for styling.

[image]